# clausal normal form

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus, symbolic-computation

I am trying to solve a problem, the solution of which I already have, the thing is that I am not understanding a step in it. Basically I don't get it why this premise **(p ⇒ q) ⇒ (q ⇒ r)**, gets transformed like this **{p, ¬q, r}
{¬q, r}**   .

Whole exercise and solution:

Question: Given these premises: p, (p ⇒ q), and (p ⇒ q) ⇒ (q ⇒ r) conclude to r. 
Breaking down in clausal form:

1. {p} Premise
2. {¬p, q} Premise
3. **{p, ¬q, r}**  Premise
4. **{¬q, r}** Premise
5. {¬r}    Premise
6. {q} 1, 2
7. {r} 4, 6
8. {}  5, 7

Thank you very much !!

Answer (score 1):

Converting to CNF:

$(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r) \Leftrightarrow$ (Implication x 3)

$\neg (\neg p \lor q) \lor (\neg q \lor r) \Leftrightarrow$ (De Morgan)

$(p \land \neg q) \lor (\neg q \lor r) \Leftrightarrow$ (Distribution)

$(p \lor \neg q \lor r) \land (\neg q \lor \neg q \lor r) \Leftrightarrow$ (Idempotence)

$(p \lor \neg q \lor r) \land (\neg q \lor r)$

So, you get clauses $\{ p , \neg q , r\}$ and $\{ \neg q , r \}$